# Visual representation of nodes in Python

Tags: python

I have data that I want to represent visually. The actual data is a tree made up of nodes. Each node has a bunch of data associated with it, but as far as this question goes, I just want a way to represent a tree visually using Python. Any ideas?

The different solutions that popped in my head were to use a GUI library like WxPython or PyQT, or maybe even a PDF generator like ReportLab. I'm hoping there's a library out there that deals closer with data so that I don't have to think out the plotting locations of all the nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is applicable to your situation, but have you looked at [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)? 
It has decent python bindings for it and I've used it for visualizing dependencies which sometimes end up looking like trees.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using graphviz directly, consider using the visualization tools included in [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/).  The graph objects there are excellent for many purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a textual representation of the tree. Otherwise, I'd go with graphviz (dotty, actually).

```
[root]
+------child1
+------child2
    +-------child3
    +-------child4
```

To show the same tree in graphviz, put this in a text file:

```
digraph graphname {
    root -> child1;
    root -> child2;
    child2 -> child3;
    child2 -> child4;
}
```

Then run dotty on it, or your tool or choice.